# JHipster Microservices Application deployment to CloudFoundry

Tags: jhipster

I am big fan of JHipster. I found it extremely useful in getting started with web applications development, deployment to cloud.

I have been trying to make the JHipster Microservices application work but with no luck. I followed the steps in the video tutorial from JHipster site but ran into issues.. Here's what I have tried..

1) Downloaded JHipster Registry and could deploy to CloudFoundry.. 
2) Created a microservice application and stuck at below message while deploying to cloudFoundry..

FAILED
Error restarting application: Start app timeout

TIP: Application must be listening on the right port. Instead of hard coding the port, use the $PORT
 environment variable.

Use 'cf logs programservice --recent' for more information

Any help on this topic is highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have never deployed to cloudfoundry myself but are you sure your app is correctly configured to connect to the jhipster-registry's address. As far as I know this must be done manually.

An alternative could be to use an Eureka Registry provided by Cloudfoundry itself rather than the jhipster-registry. You should really refer to the Cloudfoundry docs and the Cloudfoundry page of the JHipster website.